# Get intermediate output of layers on MCU using tflite micro?

Tags: c++, neural-network, microcontroller, tensorflow-lite

Sorry for the unclarity of my first question, I have edited it to be more specific.

Because the output from the middle layers in some neural network is very interesting, I would like to get the output of certain layer during the inference on a micro-controller(MCU) running tf-lite micro c++ library.

The normal way to do this in tensorflow:

```
# The model we train
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
...
])
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

# Creat a aux-model which includes the layers until the one we want
layer_output_model = Model(model.inputs, model.layers[theIndexYouWant].outputs)
```

When we put the model into MCU, we will first quantize/prune the model, convert it into a C array and flash the model to MCU, like this:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_mnist_model, "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

And the inference will be called in c++ like this:

```
# Initialization
const tflite::Model* model = ::tflite::GetModel(model);
TfLiteTensor* input = interpreter.input(0);
TfLiteTensor* output = interpreter.output(0);

# Give input, run inference and get output
input->data.f[0] = 0.;
TfLiteStatus invoke_status = interpreter.Invoke();
float value = output->data.f[0];
```

**If I want to extract the output of certain middle layer during inference in the MCU, how could I do it?**

The only method I can come up with now is convert the above aux-model `layer_output_model` into c array and upload this as an additional model to MCU.

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(layer_output_model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
aux_tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

**Is this the right way to do? I'm not sure the aux_model I converted here is the same representation of the wanted model layer output, especially after quantization using representative_dataset**

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you be more specific? Your question seems very broad and not related to programming. If you have some code/a MWE, this probably would help people to answer your question.

Comment: @user1729210 Thanks for the tipp, I just edited the problem.